# Images Not Saving in Channel Entry

Tags: channel, fieldtype, image, entry

Bit of a weird problem. We are able to upload images successfully via the basic publish entry form, but if an edit is made to the entry (even if it's just a text edit), the image disappears from the entry. Worse, though the field is marked as required, no error is thrown to notify the user that the image isn't being saved in the entry. Permissions are correct, directories are correct--I'm at a loss.

-D

Answer (score 0):

Was a bug in 3.2.0; answer posted here and supposedly fixed in 3.2.1 -- https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21679/images-disappear-and-need-to-be-reentered-into-fields

-D